# How to create OAuth HMAC-SHA1 signature on GAE/J?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, hmac

EDIT: [java equivalent to php's hmac-SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609899/java-equivalent-to-phps-hmac-sha1)
(well hopefully, trying a.t.m.)

My understanding is that to create a signature I need a 'base string' and a 'key'. I guess I know how to create the base string, and I assume I'm supposed to use 'OAuth Consumer Secret' that Google have assigned to my app as the key.

But what am I supposed to do with these two to obtain the signature? Is there any HMAC-class on GAE/Java?

Would it play if I just stored somewhere what [OAuth Playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/) generates for me? Is it how you do it? Or does OAuth signature have some expiration date?

(I tried AuthSub before but [failed too](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/msg/58693d1ca41f2dc6), even though it looks quite simple. Also OAuth seems like more 'standard' to me, so I'd like to stick with OAuth.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public String computeHmac(String baseString, String key)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalStateException, UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), mac.getAlgorithm());
    mac.init(secret);
    byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(baseString.getBytes());
    return Base64.encode(digest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason hmac_init on Quercus and GAE gives errors. One solution is to use above mentioned java method and class, import it to PHP instance and call compute.

1) Add scr/phpgae directory id you dont have yet
2) Add phpgae.HmacSHA256 line to src/WEB-INF/services/com.caucho.QuercusModule
3) Add scr/phpgae/HmacSHA256.java to your GAE application:

`package phpgae;`

```
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.Mac;

import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import com.caucho.util.Base64;

import com.caucho.quercus.module.AbstractQuercusModule;

public class HmacSHA256 extends AbstractQuercusModule {

    public String compute(String baseString, String key) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Mac mac;
        mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), mac.getAlgorithm());
        mac.init(secret);
        byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(baseString.getBytes());
        return Base64.encode(digest);
    }
}
```

Note I'm using SHA256 here. Eclipse compiles everything on fly, otherwise you need to complile class manually.

4) On PHP here is what you do:

```
<?php

import phpgae.HmacSHA256;

$c = new HmacSHA256;

echo $c->compute( 'your base string' ,  'your key' );

?>
```

You can find more practical [PHP on Google App Engine](http://php-apps.appspot.com/) examples from: http://php-apps.appspot.com/