# hash_hmac analog for Java

Tags: java, php, md5, hmac

I need to get string's hash in Java, same as for PHP's hash_hmac.

Here's my PHP sample:

```
$secret_key = 'foo';
$sig_str = 'bar';
$hash = hash_hmac('md5', $sig_str, $secret_key);
```

And that's what I found for Java:

```
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec("foo".getBytes(), "HmacMD5");
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(keySpec.getAlgorithm());
mac.init(keySpec);
String result = new BASE64Encoder().encode(mac.doFinal("bar".getBytes()));
```

But results are different. What am I missing?

Comment: Character encoding perhaps?  ->getBytes("UTF-8")  Or match to whatever PHP worked with.  As is your code would be platform specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java equivalent to php's hmac-SHA1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609899/java-equivalent-to-phps-hmac-sha1)

Comment: What is the result for both cases? Maybe they are the same, php uses HEX, but on Java you encode using Base64.

Comment: @KonstantinosChalkias yes, that was a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution here: [java equivalent to php's hmac-SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609899/java-equivalent-to-phps-hmac-sha1)

The problem was in BASE64Encoder. Use

```
for (byte b : digest) {
    System.out.format("%02x", b);
}
System.out.println();
```

or

```
new BigInteger(digest).toString(16);
```

instead.