# SHA 256 for android app

Tags: java, php, android, sha, ash

I have in PHP this method to call a security web service:

```
// token generator; date is UTC/GMT
$tokenNewInputData = date("Y-m-d");
$tokenNew = hash_hmac('sha256', $tokenNewInputData, KEY);
echo ‘token: ‘.$tokenNew;
```

where KEY it's "password" text.

I must use the same method into Android app for generate a security code in the same way and add this to a string for get call.

Can you help me please for an example to traslate this PHP code into Android code?
Thanks.

Comment: Is it the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609899/java-equivalent-to-phps-hmac-sha1 ?

Answer (score 0):

write down below code.

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
String text = "This is some text";
md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8")); // Change this to "UTF-16" if needed
byte[] digest = md.digest();
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, but i have a error for :md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));. Unhandled exception

Comment: I have the same error if i use UTF-16